# HDRI light the mesh in viewport render (shift + z) but not in final render

Tags: rendering, hdri

I use the add on easy HDRI, it work when I use the viewport render with shift Z, they add light to my mesh but when I make the final render they don't have any effect on the mesh.

My scene only contain a camera, a shpere and a light on the right of that shpere.

[image]
[image]

The environnement passe is checked:
[image]

as you can see on the render layer node, i try to see only the influence of the HDRI on the mesh [image]

but It seems There is no light coming from the environnement.
[image]

Here I join the blender file, I would appreciate if someone can help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that use Environement wasn't checked in the layer section of render layer.
Instead Environement was checked on the passes section, which is useless if Use environement is uncked.

[image]

The Environement passe is not responsible of the light on the mesh, it just show the environement (in my case the HDRI I use to light the scene. 
Here is an environement passe:[image]